# Linq unwrap a nested foreach

Tags: c#, linq

how can i turn the following nested `foreach` loop into a Linq expression?

Thanks

```
        List<Plan> plans = new List<Plan>();

        foreach (var planning in plannings)
        {
            foreach (var plan in planning)
            {
                plans.Add(plan);
            }                
        }
```

I'd like to see it done with lambda expression ( `.Select()` ) more than with the `from .. select` syntax, if possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var plans = plannings.SelectMany(p => p);
```

Comment: you should add .ToList() in the end to materealize enumerator

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Plan> plans = plannings.SelectMany(ps => ps).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here's the query syntax version:

```
var query = from planning in plannings
            from plan in planning
            select plan;

List<Plan> plans = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Plan> plans = new List<Plan>();

        foreach (var plan in plans.SelectMany(planning => planning))
        {
            newPlans.Add(plan as Plan);
        }
```

..might work!